# Convert GRAPHSON_V2D0 Serializer response to GRAPHSON

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, tinkergraph

Azure cosmos support `Serializers.GRAPHSON_V2D0`. `List<Result> resultList = client.submit("g.V().limit(1)").all().get()` returns all the properties with the vertex and the format is completely different. `Result` looks like

```json
{
    "resultObject": {
        "id": "63073513-1e86-49e6-a949-07f1e16c782b",
        "label": "TYPE-1",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
            "prop1": [
                {
                    "id": "63073513-1e86-49e6-a949-07f1e16c782b",
                    "value": "value1"
                }
            ],
            
        }
    }
}
```

But if I use Traversal with TinkerGraph, the default result uses `Serializers.GRAPHSON` where the result looks like

```json
[
    {
        "id": "63073513-1e86-49e6-a949-07f1e16c782b",
        "label": "TYPE-1"
    }
]
```

For small result we can put a layer to covert the result but won't be straight forward thing for complex `Path` and other queries. I tried `GraphSONMapper` but didn't work.
Is there any way to convert `Serializers.GRAPHSON_V2D0` to `Serializers.GRAPHSON`? Or can we get `GraphSON` result from Cosmos?

Comment: Are you using TinkerGraph with a Gremlin Server or some other configuration? If with Gremlin Server you can configure the server to return any of the supported serialization formats.

Comment: Actually I don't have that option to change the response format as the response is consumed by multiple clients so I'm trying to find a way to get the same result on Cosmos Gremlin DB.

Comment: Ah actually, I understand what you need now. I will add an answer

Comment: I tried to use Serializers.GRAPHSON_V2D0 while creating Cluster object for Neptune then it returned same result as Cosmos. By default it uses Serializers.GRAPHSON_V3D0/Serializers.GRAPHSON and send the MIME type accordingly so the response are different in both the cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually due to the serializers. It is due to the fact that, by default, Gremlin Server only returns a "Reference Element" for a vertex. It will just contain its ID and label. You can disable that by editing the script file in the `<gremlin-server-root>/scripts` folder. In there, the default file used is called `empty-sample.groovy`. At the bottom of that file you will find this line:

```java
globals << [g : traversal().withEmbedded(graph).withStrategies(ReferenceElementStrategy)]
```

All you need to do is to replace it with just

```java
globals << [g : traversal().withEmbedded(graph)]
```

Having done that, restart the server and you should see all properties as well as the ID and label.

Comment: Can we do that on cosmos DB?

Comment: This is something you can do to make a Gremlin Server match what you mentioned you are getting back from CosmosDB (nodes that include all their property values).. There are two different things in play here. (1) disabling the ReferenceElementStrategy for Gremlin server to enable getting properties back, and (2) Using GraphSONV2 everywhere so that whichever DB you connect to - Gremlin Server/Amazon Neptune/CosmosDB - you will get the same serialization. Currently Neptune will only return a ReferenceElement however. Making that user configurable is on the Apache TinkerPop roadmap.

Comment: It might be better to explicitly ask for the properties you need using either `valueMap` or `elementMap` rather than rely on a specific DB behavior. That way you will have more control over the data that is returned regardless of the back-end implementation.

Comment: Looks like impossible as of now as Cosmos has so many limitations. Explicitly getting the values is the option we had in mind, but this involves changes at consumers end as well. Thanks @Kelvin!